# Treegrid ASP error con el css ó jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Tengo un espacio designado para una griview ASP.NET C# que se genera tras un evento. Este griview es un grid tipo arbol (treegrid).

Aquí les doy una muestra de cómo tiene que se correctamente:

(este tabla html la copie de mi proyecto en el DOMREADY )
[TREEGRID BUENO](https://jsfiddle.net/nacs2025/2kejkedn/)

El gran problema al que me enfrento es que el grid en asp se genera automáticamente en mi proyecto lo tengo así:

```
  <div class="tree-pane">

  <asp:GridView ID="GVInteresASP" runat="server" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" CssClass="GridviewScrollItem tree-2" OnRowCreated="TreeCss" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                    </asp:GridView>   

  </div>
```

El css "tree-pane" enmarcar la tabla de tal manera que cada vez que se abra una rama el scroll del webpage no cambie de tamaño, sino el scroll interno.

Tal vez alguien ha trabajado con esto anteriormente. Pero algo tiene que el jquery no reconoce el futuro height del grid y define un height por defecto y la ramificación no se llega a desplegar toda...sola la mitad xq la otra queda oculta dentro del div.

Traté con poner 100% de height al grid, también 1000 px (éste me jode gráficamente el header y alto de las celdas pero siempre predomina el error)

No se en realidad como resolver este asunto. No puedo replicar el error porque ocurre cuando se corre el proyecto cuando el grid aun no tiene datos.

Answer (score 0):

No comprendo muy bien el problema, pero y si intentas hacer el llamado en el pageLoad()?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad()
    {
        $('.tree-2').treegrid({
            initialState: 'expand',
            expanderExpandedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus',
            expanderCollapsedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Sorry, el error ha sido resuelto todo estaba bien excepto 'GridviewScrollItem' - esta clase la ocupaba en un jquery para otro grid y era quien me creaba el conflicto. asi que si generaba la pag a un 70% ejemplo el jquery para el tree no se ejecutaba.

Comment: @N'oelC'alero deberías poner ese comentario como respuesta y aceptarlo como válido